# Generic HighCharts (Javascript\Java)

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, highcharts

I have searched for ages but couldn't find what I am looking for.
I'm using highCharts.

Is there a method or project or something that creates generic highcharts charts for me? Currently I must make a javascript chart function for every chart I want. I want to make this generic.

So that I only have to ask the method getChart('line','etc'); something like this.
This way i dont have to code everything over and over again for each chart that I want.
(its for a Dashboard )

If this doesn't exists at all I will make it myself.

Comment: So you would like to have i.e form where user chooses type of chart and chart is generated or something different ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several libraries out there for producing highcharts. Many are listed on the highcharts download page here: http://www.highcharts.com/download under 'API Wrappers:'.

If you are most confortable working in Java, maybe you should check out GWT and the GWT Highcharts wrapper. GWT lets you write Java code, which compiles down into javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Those ones are the bests http://www.highcharts.com/ i tried them and they work absolutely fine with great design just download them and make us know if you get problemes using them.